# Bukkit API 1.16.4: Вместо нужного типа предмета выдаёт AIR

Tags: java, bukkit-api

Я пытаюсь получить тип предмета из инвентаря игрока методом `item.getType().toString()`. Если игрок держит обычный предмет, который есть в более ранних версиях майнкрафта, то всё работает, если игрок держит землю, то DIRT, если алм. меч, то DIAMOND_SWORD. **Но если игрок берёт в руку предмет, который добавили только в новых версиях (1.15, 1.16), например незеритовый нагрудник или сладкие ягоды, то выдаёт просто AIR, вместо того чтобы вывести ID предмета (типа NETHERITE_CHESTPLATE). Как это можно исправить?**

Answer (score 0):

Весьма вероятно, что Вы используете старую версию API (для 1.14 или версий старше). Если это так, то проблема исправляется следующим образом в Eclipse (в IntelIJ, думаю, будет точно также):

1. Заходите в настройки проекта;
2. Переходите во вкладку "Java Build Path";
3. Удаляет старую версию Bukkit.jar;
4. Добавляете новую там же.